# Confused about the necessity of multplying the covariance function by a scaling factor in Gaussian Process modeling

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, pymc

I was reviewing examples of implementing GP-based model with PyMC3. I noticed some examples will multiply the covairance function by a factor, which is in turn modeled as a random variable, while others do not.

For examples, in https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GP-Latent.html, it adds such scaling factor. The relevant lines are as below

```
η = pm.HalfCauchy("η", beta=1)
cov = η ** 2 * pm.gp.cov.Matern52(1, ℓ)
gp = pm.gp.Latent(cov_func=cov)
```

But in https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GP-Marginal.html, it does not add such scaling factor. The relevant lines are as below

```
# Specify the covariance function.
cov_func = pm.gp.cov.ExpQuad(1, ls=0.1)

# Specify the GP.  The default mean function is `Zero`.
gp = pm.gp.Marginal(cov_func=cov_func)
```

My questions are

1. what is the actual difference made by adding such scaling factor. My understanding is it will only change the variance of value of f(x) at each x, but does not change the correlation of f(x) values at different x vallues. Am I right?
2. when should we try to model this factor and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scale factor allows you to translate the default covariance functions (under which $\text{Var}[f(x)]=1$) into the actual covariance function you want to associate to $f(x)$ in your prior. It does not affect the correlation between any $f(x)$ and $f(x')$, although it does affect their covariance (multiplying it by $\eta^2$).

Now, when do you need such a scaling factor? Whenever you don't want a distribution with $\text{Var}[f(x)]=1$. Then, you can use a deterministic scaling factor (just multiplying that covariance function by some float) or you can learn the scale from the data itself (like the first example in your question).

For example, if one were modeling average height of children as a function of time. Would it make sense to have $\text{Var}[f(x)]=1$? It would certainly depend on the units that are being used, and it would make sense to multiply the covariance function by some scale factor in centimeters or inches.

And even if $f(x)$ has no units, you may want it to have a variance greater than 1, or smaller than 1. Scale factors allow you to choose this variance at your own discretion, or even consider put a prior on it, instead of just taking the default value of $1$ for granted.

Hope it was helpful

Comment: Thanks @PedroSebe.  If the y value of the samples has been standarized (i.e. mean=0, stdev=1), is that fair to say this scaling factor is not needed?

Comment: yes, I think it's fair to say so